# Access json-returning php functions from javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have a php file that creates a json output. my problem is that i will need lots of functions that return json data. For example:

1. i will need to fetch a list of all customers in a given db;
2. I will need to fetch all vehicles from a given customer;
3. i will need to fetch all data from a given vehicle

and so on. At this point i can have all this working if each function is in a separate php file. The complexity of this is only going to increase and i dont want to have lots of files cluttering the file system. Is there a way around this? any practical example would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. If you have one function for each type of action, like this:

```
function action_hello_world() {
    echo "Hello, world!";
}
function action_hello() {
    echo "Hello, {$_GET["name"]}!";
}
```

Then create an array of valid actions:

```
$valid_actions=array("hello_world", "hello");
```

Then we have a GET parameter called `action`:

```
$action=$_GET["action"];
```

We check to make sure it's valid...

```
if(!in_array($action, $valid_actions)) {
    die("Invalid action.");
}
```

Then we call the correct function:

```
$function_name="action_$action";
$function_name();
```

Comment: ok, but that code is php. how do i call these different functions on javascript? what would be the .getJSON relevant parameters?

Comment: @sergio: `$.getJSON("some_file.php?action=hello_world", ...)`